# Systemd script not writing into a .txt file

Tags: bash, systemd

I'm trying to make a systemd unit that runs a script continuously checking for differences between two txt files and writes the difference into a third:

```
[Unit]
Description=something

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/home/myuser/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

log=/home/myuser/test.txt

log2=/home/myuser/test2.txt

while true
do
     lshw -short > $log

     if ! diff "${log}" "${log2}"; then
     date >> alert.txt
     diff "${log}" "${log2}" >> alert.txt
     fi
done
```

The script works fine and the service journal tells me that the service is working, however it never writes into the "alert.txt" file.

Any solutions?

Comment: Use a fully qualified path instead of `alert.txt`.

Comment: Thank you my friend it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a fully qualified path for your script when executing it via a SystemD script.  That way, it knows where to store the file data to on-disk.

So instead of `alert.txt` give it a full path, for example `/home/user/alert.txt` or `/tmp/alert.txt` or similar.